# Check the logic regarding RLE in python

Tags: python, string

this is a question regarding Run Length Encoding where the error is coming up as string index out of range.Also the count value is coming up after every occurence of  a character.
Ideal output should be - 1A4B8C1A1B
Kindly provide with your views and alternatives

```
#PF-Assgn-30

def encode(message):
str1=""
count=0
#Remove pass and write your logic here
for var in range(0,len(message)):
    count=1
    while(message[var]==message[var+1]):
        count+=1
        var+=1
    str1=str(count)+message[var]
return str1    
#Provide different values for message and test your program
encoded_message=encode("ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB")
print(encoded_message)
```

Comment: `var` ranges from 0 to `len(message) - 1`, so two lines later when you say `message[var+1]`, the last iteration of the `for` loop will set `var` such that you're trying to access `message[len(message)]`, an index that will never exist.  Note this is not the only issue with getting your program to work as expected, but it's the next step.

Comment: So Jedwards,what changes would you suggest I can make in this code?